# Which statistical test can I applied for two groups, control and experimental?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Sorry if my question is a little silly. I did an experiment about the effect of a drug, so I designed an experiment with two groups: the control group(without any intervention) and the experimental group (which subjects received the drug). Each group has aprox. the same number of samples.

The subjects in the experimental group had received three doses of the drug with different variations in three different times. To evaluate the impact of the drug, after some days, it was collected a multivariate type of data (pressure, temperature, blood measures, etc).

I read about the T test, however, in each example, the test only compares the mean of a single data attribute, so my question is if it exists a T test for multivariate data. Also, if it exists how can I take into consideration the three different times of the application of the drug (can I do simple mean?)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Anova or look at multiple testing procedures. Search a bit